# Selection with xPath (PHP)

Tags: php, laravel

I have this XML code :

```
  <img src='something' width='16' height='16' alt='Icone Pays de production' title='Pays de production' class='base' > 
<strong>Pays de production :</strong> <a href='index.php?p=pays&pays=96' class='no'>Hongrie</a> 
<br>
```

I am trying to retrieve "Hongrie", I tried this :

```
//img[contains(@title, 'Pays de production')]
```

That just select the img, and when I try :

```
//img[contains(@title, 'Pays de production')]//strong//a
```

This just returns false

Comment: As the A tag isn't inside the strong tag, `//img[contains(@title, 'Pays de production')]/a`?

Comment: Is this actually XML or just HTML?

Comment: Nigel, when I try your solution I have : No elements found. And for Jaob, it is HTML.

Comment: Try `//img[contains(@title, 'Pays de production')]/following-sibling::a[text()]`